# SQL "$" symbol usage

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been looking at a SQL query & output and am trying to figure out the impact the "$" would have in the query if any.

I cannot find anything about the use of the "$" symbol and want to make sure. I've searched the w3 schools, here, and Oracle documentation (as I'm using an Oracle database)

```
select * from v$example_users
```

The above is the code that I'm looking at. Will the "$" symbol in the middle of the table name? I.e. is the table called "v$example_users" or does the "$" somehow affect the table?

Comment: There is no impact. That is simply the name of the table. See [the Oracle naming rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm) for a complete list of what is or is not valid in table names.

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is just a normal symbol, just like a or 1, it is sometimes used as a separator in names as a form of namespacing (ie as a poor man's schema).

Comment: Used extensively in Oracle's data dictionary.

Comment: Hi @ChrisHep, that reference has just what I needed. Thank you for sending!  From Oracle's reference "Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#). Database links can also contain periods (.) and "at" signs (@). Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in nonquoted identifiers."

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel, thank you for the info! I had totally forgotten about schemas and was just focusing my search on operators.

Comment: Oracle (as recent as 10g) used to discourage the use of $ in non-quoted identifiers.  The 10g SQL Language Reference contained this line: "Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in nonquoted identifiers.".  They appear to have dropped that though.

Comment: To be clear, this has nothing to do with schemas themselves, it is just that some people namespace things with this instead of using real schemas.

Comment: @Mark, I def appreciate the clarification. I get what you're saying that it's for identification and doesn't affect actual schemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no special functionality to the `$` character.

The `v$` views are public synonyms of Oracle's [dynamic performance views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A58617_01/server.804/a58242/ch3.htm). They are given these "unconventional" names to make them easy to recognize.

Answer (score -1):

Most Oracle identifiers (table names, column names, etc.) you see in the wild usually include only alphanumeric characters. This is largely because it's easy to type and it reduces confusion with math operators, parenthesis, and other delimiters. This is also true for all databases I know.

However, you can actually use other symbols for table names (or other "objects") if you want to. If you do, you will probably need to quote the name -- every time. That is, when you `create` the table, when you `insert` a row, when you `delete` and `update` it, and on **every** single `select` query where you use it. It's perfectly legal, so if you need it, use it.

And, there's no performance penalty to pay. For Oracle there's no difference.

For example:

```
create table "Car+Price" (
  id number(6),
  "list&price" number(6),
  "%discount" number(3),
  "used?" number(1)
);
```

But then a query would be:

```
select id, "list&price", "%discount"
  from "Car+Price"
  where "used?" = 1;
```

See? Works! Does it look nice? er... not really. Besides, it looks quite error prone to me.

In my opinion, I would strongly recommend against using it (if possible) since it makes code harder to read, it's more difficult to debug, some ORMs don't really deal well with it, and a myriad of other reasons.

Just stay away from it, as long as you can.

Comment: This is not correct, the `$` is allowed in an identifier without the need for quoting (just like `_` and `#`).

Comment: Modified accordingly to "&" and "+".

Comment: With that change, you are no longer addressing the question that is specifically about `$`.

Comment: You're right. I was referring to special chars in generall. Off topic. Will delete the answer. -- Can't delete it since it's "accepted".